# Convert column to row and sum query in different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i trying to figure to convert sumtchtraffic and totalpayloadGb column in sitetable and sum data totalpayloadGb & sumtchtraffic where BTS_TYPE 2g, 3g and 4g in techtable

i tried like this, but i cant show totalpayloadgb & sumtchtraffic in column [SUM OF] ([sum of] is not in any table in my database)

```
select * from (select
sum(case when techtable.BTS_TYPE='2G' then sitetable.TotalPayloadGb else 0 end) as [Total 2G],
sum(case when techtable.BTS_TYPE='3G' then sitetable.TotalPayloadGb else 0 end) as [Total 3G],
sum (case when techtable.BTS_TYPE='4G'then sitetable.TotalPayloadGb else 0 end) as [Total 4G]

from sitetable 

inner join techtable on sitetable.sitename = techtable.sitename) as t
```

I want show my data like this:
[image: I want show my data like this]

Comment: Hi, I think this question is easier to answer if you could also post sample data from the tables (sitetable and techtable?) that your query is based on. Otherwise, its almost impossible to guess the right query for the right answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to total your results separately, using the same conditional aggregation you have started, and then `UNION` the results together. Since your first column doesn't exist anywhere else, you'll have to hard-code it into the queries.

```sql
SELECT 
    'TotalPayloadGb' AS SumOf,
    sum(CASE WHEN t.BTS_TYPE = '2G' THEN s.TotalPayloadGb ELSE 0 END) AS [Total 2G],
    sum(CASE WHEN t.BTS_TYPE = '3G' THEN s.TotalPayloadGb ELSE 0 END) AS [Total 3G],
    sum(CASE WHEN t.BTS_TYPE = '4G' THEN s.TotalPayloadGb ELSE 0 END) AS [Total 4G]
FROM sitetable AS s
INNER JOIN techtable AS t
    ON s.sitename = t.sitename
UNION
SELECT 
    'SumTCHTraffic' AS SumOf,
    sum(CASE WHEN t.BTS_TYPE = '2G' THEN s.SumTCHTraffic ELSE 0 END) AS [Total 2G],
    sum(CASE WHEN t.BTS_TYPE = '3G' THEN s.SumTCHTraffic ELSE 0 END) AS [Total 3G],
    sum(CASE WHEN t.BTS_TYPE = '4G' THEN s.SumTCHTraffic ELSE 0 END) AS [Total 4G]
FROM sitetable AS s
INNER JOIN techtable AS t
    ON s.sitename = t.sitename;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do, you could do like this:

```
 SELECT tt.BTS_Type, sum(st.TotalPayloadDb)
 FROM SiteTable st
    INNER JOIN TechTable as tt on st.sitename = tt.sitename
```

This will give one row per BTS_Type value.

Comment: i had this query, but still not like picture i shared



select techtable.bts_type, sum(sitetable.sumtchtraffic) as [Total Traffic],
sum(sitetable.totalpayloadGb) as [Total Payload]
from sitetable
inner join techtable on sitetable.sitename = techtable.sitename
group by TechTable.BTS_TYPE